# Bootstrap Typeahead local, prefetch, or remote is required

Tags: javascript, jquery, typeahead.js, bootstrap-typeahead, twitter-typeahead

I try to get [this example](http://www.deanhume.com/Home/BlogPost/twitter-bootstrap-typeahead-and-asp-net-mvc---key-value-pairs/88) of twitters typeahead to run but i am getting the error in chromes console:

> Uncaught Error: one of local, prefetch, or remote is required jquery-1.9.1.js:507

I am using typeayhead 0.9.1 (Nuget-Package). Is this a version problem? All examples set the source and not local/prefetch/remote in the request.

EDIT: Turned out that Twitter Bootstrap Typeahead and Twitter Typeahead are two different libraries.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This only means you need to give a list in which Typeahead will search for completion value.

You must really pass at least one data source (`prefetch` or `remote`) or a data set (`local`).

https://github.com/twitter/typeahead.js#jquerytypeaheaddatasets

---

Also, should be noted that [*Twitter typeahead*](http://twitter.github.io/typeahead.js/) and [*Twitter Bootstrap typeahead*](http://twitter.github.io/bootstrap/javascript.html#typeahead) ain't the same plugin. They have different API. The article you read speak about Twitter Bootstrap typeahead: http://twitter.github.io/bootstrap/javascript.html#typeahead but you used it as Twitter typeahead!

Comment: no? look at the example. Nearly in all examples i find the `source` attribute is set and not `local/prefetch/remote`

Comment: Oh, I see what the problem is. _Twitter Typeahead_ and _Twitter Bootstrap typeahead_ ain't the same plugin. They have different API. The article you read speak about twitter bootstrap typeahead: http://twitter.github.io/bootstrap/javascript.html#typeahead

Comment: yes i did also think that these are the same projects...