# conflict with typeahead, php and jquery 1.10.2

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql

I have the following code in JavaScript:

```
$('input#search_user').typeahead({

            source: function(query, process) {
                    $.ajax({
                        url: 'modulos/search_user.php', 
                        type: 'POST',
                        data: 'query=' + query,
                        dataType: 'JSON',
                        async: true,
                        success: function(data) {
                            process(data);
                            console.log(data);
                        }
                    });
                }                                                             
        });
```

And the following code in my PHP file:

```
 if (isset($_POST['query'])) {
    $query = $_POST['query'];
    $sql = mysql_query ("SELECT nombre FROM users_r WHERE nombre LIKE '%{$query}%'",$link);

  }

  $data = array();
  while ($row = mysql_fetch_object($sql)) 
  {
    $data[] = $row['nombre'];
  }
  echo json_encode( $data );
  mysql_close($link);
```

But with jQuery 1.10.2 it throws the following error:

> Uncaught Error: one of local, prefetch, or remote is required

What should I do about this?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Bootstrap Typeahead local, prefetch, or remote is required](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16089875/bootstrap-typeahead-local-prefetch-or-remote-is-required)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

now works with the next code

javascript

```
    $(document).ready(function () 
    {
       $("input[name='search_user']").typeahead({
        name: 'nombre',
        remote: 'modulos/search_user.php?query=%QUERY'                                                          
    });
    }); // $(document).ready(function ()
```

php file

```
   $query = $_GET['query'];
    $sql = mysql_query ("SELECT nombre FROM users_r WHERE nombre LIKE '%{$query}%'",$link);
    $data = array();
    while ($row =  mysql_fetch_assoc($sql)) 
    {
            $data[] = $row['nombre'];
    }
    mysql_close($link);
    echo json_encode( $data );
```

my problem was the each method, for get column work with mysql_fetch_assoc but no with mysql_fetch_object